# async await not functioning in order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

async seems to go over my head, I just don't get it.

I've looked at other questions but can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

I have included below a chunk of my code which I have tested and I still experience the same issue.

When trying to await for the two files to download it appears my files are downloaded while everything else executes (in this case console.log).

I expect `console.info('Done.');` to run after the files have been downloaded, but this is not the case. This is important as later on the files are uploaded (also have the same issue with uploading) and I get important data back after uploading. This needs to be stored for later use.

TL;DR, `console.info('Done.');` is being executed before `dataPortDOWN()` is completed.

```js
//Imports
const   fs            = require('fs'),
        { promisify } = require('util'),
        asyncPipeline = promisify(require("stream").pipeline),
        { once }      = require("events"),
        csv           = require('csv-parser'),
        fetch         = require('node-fetch');

//Download file
async function fetchBody (url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);

    if (!response.ok)
        throw oops;

    return response.body;
}

//Calling downloads
async function dataPortDOWN () {
  const csvAsync = csv();

  fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
    .pipe(csvAsync).
    on("data", async (row) => {
      if (row.Timestamp === "")
        return;

      /* */
      const sigUrl = row['removed'].replace("removed", "removed"),
            picUrl = row['removed'].replace("removed", "removed"),
            id     = row['removed'].replace("removed", "removed");

      const [ sigBody, picBody ] = await Promise.all([
        fetchBody(sigUrl),
        fetchBody(picUrl),
      ]);

      const sigLocalFile = fs.createWriteStream(`${id}-sig.jpg`),
            picLocalFile = fs.createWriteStream(`${id}-pic.jpg`);

      sigBody.pipe(sigLocalFile);
      picBody.pipe(picLocalFile);

      await once(sigLocalFile, "finish");
      await once(picLocalFile, "finish");

      /* */
    })

    await once(csvAsync, "finish");
}

async function main() {
  await dataPortDOWN();
  console.info(`Done.`);
}

main();
```

Comment: @Nit it would only throw a `ReferenceError` if `response.ok` is false. While not ideal, I don't think it alone would stop this code from working as expected.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you're waiting for the `finish` event of that CSV stream, but you are not waiting for the processing that is started on each `data` event.

Comment: Given readable streams are asynchronously iterable, you might want to try `for await (const row of fs.createReadStream('data.csv').pipe(csvAsync)) { … /* await */ }` which would do everything strictly sequentially.

Comment: I'll give that a go soon, can't right now. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: I tried what @Bergi recommended and it only downloaded one set of the files then didn't log Done